# Google Maps v3 Marker shadow z-index

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I replaced marker shadow for background image of icon, so it will look like a frame of the image. And it looks fine. The problem is that somehow shadows has the same z-index so if two markers are together we can't see the frame (other image covers it). Because every icon has grater value of z-index than shadow. How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marker-shadows are always placed inside a different overlay(overlayShadow) , so you will not have any chance to move a shadow in front of any marker.

There may be different options, for example you can ommit the shadow and create a second marker using the shadow-image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Guess I will have to make my own markers then.